# WordPress on VPS running Plesk, no mail is being sent out

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plesk

I have a VPS server running PLESK(12.5.30) and all of the WordPress forms we have that are supposed to send to people who fill out forms, are not being sent. They are just sitting in the mail queue as 'deferred'.

I think it has to do with php mail, but I can't seem to get this to work and my host is literally no help at all. I even called Plesk and they did not help.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your `"From:"` address is a valid email address on your server. Use their email address as a `"Reply-to:"` address - seems to solve a lot of those kinds of problems - also make sure the `sendmail_from` setting has the same email address as you use for the `"From:"` address using `ini_set( 'sendmail_from', 'your_email@your_server.com');` at the top of your mail script. Also maybe take a look at contactform7 plugin for forms for WordPress which seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

For more information you can check system mail log somewhere in in /var/logs/

Take in account that setting up working server of outbound mail is a real pain. In two words you need to setup SPF and DKIM or such mail services like Gmail will mark all emails from your server as spam by default.

In your case I can suggest to SendGrid service which has a  WordPress plug-in https://wordpress.org/plugins/sendgrid-email-delivery-simplified/
(You need to register SendGrid account, it's free)

If your contact forms using default wp_mail() you mail will be send through SendGrid mail servers.

Also you can setup you Postfix/sendmail with using SendGrid's mail server: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/postfix.html